# Why did I receive an error when using ROWS UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, adventureworks

I was trying to understand the concept of window framing in SQL server. I was working with Adventure Works 2014 database. My question is we can use the `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` solely but when I tried to use the `ROWS UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` solely and I get a syntax error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'FOLLOWING'

The query is:

```sql
SELECT
    CustomerID,
    SalesOrderID,
    CAST(OrderDate AS DATE) AS OrderDate,
    TotalDue,
    SUM(TotalDue) OVER (ORDER BY CustomerID ROWS UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS RunningTotal 
FROM
    sales.SalesOrderHeader 
ORDER BY 
    CustomerID
```

Comment: I'm impressed you managed to `RESTORE` the Adventure Works 2014 database on a 2012 instance, if I am honest.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  Try:

```
    SUM(TotalDue) OVER (ORDER BY CustomerID
                        ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                       ) AS RunningTotal
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I wanted to know is when we can use ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING then why can't the same be done with ROWS UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING alone. If we try to use this ```ORDER BY CustomerID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING``` it will return a result but not the same with unbounded following